# Scrolling problem with UITableView

Tags: iphone, ios4, uinavigationbar, uitableview

!I have a UITableviewController with a navigation bar as header. there are 4 sections in the table, Number of rows in the table are more than that can be fit in the iphone screen. while scrolling whole view is getting scrolled!!. I want the header to be stationary and only table to be moved.
Also the last section is appearing twice! [like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BBosZ.png)

[Table view controller snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NE5tH.png)

please help

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

First don't use Navigation bar as the header of TableView. You should use a navigation controller and push this viewcontroller which contains tableview. This will allow you to get rid of first problem i.e. to keep the bar steady and not scroll with the tableview.

Second problem looks really weird, it seems to be that you have laid out two UITableView in your nib. Check again and remove one.

Comment: Im sorry actually I am using a navigation controller in the app delegate and pushing the view controller to it

Comment: If you would have been doing it properly the navigation bar would have never scrolled out of the screen. There is no need for you to put a custom nav bar in the UITableView header. Please check your nib to see if you have uncheck "Shows Navigation Bar" under Bar Visibility section on your nib

Comment: What your navigationController contains ?  can you provide us the screen shot ?

Comment: @NagarajaSathe That is the reason why you are not seeing the default nav bar, please recheck (on) that checkbox. That will show a default nav bar which will not scroll up with tableview

Comment: So you mean to say when you are scrolling tableview then your navigation controller hides ?

Comment: @Praveen-K No, our friend Nagaraja is using a custom navbar in the header of UITableView, that will scroll up when you scroll table view. Not the default navigation controller, it will always shows on top irrespective of table scroll. That is the main question from him, which I am trying to help

Comment: @RahulChoudhary ok, but can you tell me what your custom navbar contains? i mean what control your custom navbar holds ?

Comment: @Praveen-K you are asking question to the wrong guy. Please ask Nagaraja what his custom nav bar contained.

Comment: @RahulChoudhary,@praveen K: I solved the problem, actually it was my mistake in the code i was adding nib and navigation controller at the same time... I realized it yest eve... thanks for the answers!!:)

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:
1) add a base UIView on which your header view and your table view are siblings.
2) set the header view as the table view's viewForHeader of the first section

Comment: How the 2 option will work? if you scroll the tableview the header view will also move.

Comment: header view yes, but the section header will stay. Another option is to override UITableView and adjust your own header view position to always be at the top.

Comment: Ahhh.. that's the bad idea to put UIView in section header.

Answer (score 0):

> You have only one option:
>
> 1)create a UIView lets say headerView and add control or whatever you
>   want to have and put that custom UIView on top of your UITableView
>
> 2)Do not implement viewForHeaderInsection
>
> 3)Change the y position of your UITableView to place your tableView
>   below your headerView